# How to setup and save qemu running option

Tags: qemu

I'm using qemu to replace bochs (since it doesn't update anymore)

In bochs, I can save the running settings into files and reload it. Furthermore, there will be a listed table of running options while boot up.

I'm wondering if I can do the same with qemu, save running settings such as cpu model, and other stuffs into some files and reload it next time I run emulation.

And if there exists a full listed running option table like thing for me to have a complete view on which options I can set.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of UI and management of VMs you should look at a "management layer" program that sits on top of QEMU. libvirt's "virt-manager" is one common choice here. A management-layer will generally allow you to define options for a VM and save them so you can start and stop that VM without having to specify all the command line options every time. It will also configure QEMU in a more secure and performant way than you get by default, which often requires rather long QEMU command lines.

QEMU itself doesn't provide this kind of facility because its philosophy is to just be the low-level tool which runs a VM, and leave the UI and persistent-VM-management to other software which can do a better job of it.